# Differentiate to the $1/2$ power

Tags: calculus

Differentiate $ax^2 + b$ to the $1/2$ power. (Exact wording of question)

The answer is $2ax$.

I don't get the question. Is it ${d\over dx} \left(ax^2+b\right)^{1/2}$? If so I am getting 
$$ax\over \sqrt{a x^2+b}$$
It's only when I don't do the half power thing that I get $2ax$.

Comment: There's something very flawed with the question. It should definitely read "differentiate $ax^2+b$" since, as you note, if they meant "differentiate $\sqrt{ax^2+b}$, you get the answer in your post.

Comment: Maybe they meant $ax^2+b^{1/2}$ ?

Comment: The wording is exact?  Did they literally use a "^" sign?

Comment: If the 'to the' part of the question was really written out in english (while the other power was not) then perhaps you are only supposed to push down with your pencil at 'half power' when you write the derivative of ax^2 + b?

Comment: @ErickWong nope, sorry, im just kinda used to that notation cuz of my programming background.

Comment: @OnceUponACrinoid is correct! i get 2ax

Comment: And here I was thinking it would be a question on fractional calculus... http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fractional_calculus

Answer (score -1):

If we really talk about fractional derivatives, then it is defined as following:$$D^ax^k = \frac{d^a}{dx^a} x^k = \frac{k!}{(k-a)!}x^{k-a} = \frac{\Gamma(k+1)}{\Gamma(k-a+1)}x^{k-a}$$So using $\Gamma$ function we can define fractional derivative. It has all the properties of linear operator and is an extension of regular derivative. For example for $n = a+b$: $$D^aD^bx^k\frac{d^a}{dx^a} \frac{d^b}{dx^b}x^k = \frac{d^n}{dx^n}x^k = D^nx^k$$. To make sure it is consistent with regular derivative we set that fractional derivative of constant is zero, i.e. $D^a(const) = 0$. Then $$\frac{d^{\frac{1}{2}}}{dx^{\frac{1}{2}}} x^k = \frac{\Gamma(k+1)}{\Gamma(k+\frac{1}{2})}x^{k-\frac{1}{2}}$$For $k=2$$$D^{\frac{1}{2}}x^2 = \frac{2}{\frac{3}{4}\sqrt{\pi}}x\sqrt{x}$$ So $$D^{\frac{1}{2}}(ax^2+b) = \frac{8}{3\sqrt{\pi}}ax\sqrt{x}$$

Comment: I get the idea behind this post but it's most definitely not an answer to the question OP is asking. You've also used the least rigorous "definition" for a fractional derivative. Moreover, you have completely confused the terminology of "partial" with "fractional" which is another unfortunate mistake.

Comment: @hOff By your definition of $D^a x^k$, $D^{1/2} b$ is not zero, it's $b \Gamma(1)/\Gamma(1/2) x^{-1/2} = b/\sqrt{\pi x}$.

Comment: @Cameron Williams, Correct. In the comments poster admitted that question was about $\frac{d}{dx}(ax^2 + \sqrt(b))$. Sorry for typos, everywhere I meant fractional derivatives, not partial. Yes, I used less rigorous definitions. Grunwald-Letnikov or Caputo derivatives would be more appropriate.

Comment: @Eric Wong, I can see your point. In this case fractional derivative definition would not be consistent with full derivative and I think it is important. IMHO, better "fractionalization" of derivative is done by Grunwald-Letnikov - to keep consistency with regular derivative. ... but it is way more tedious to calculate

Comment: In my opinion this answer, although intelligent, has nothing to do with the question.

Comment: @Eric Wong, I have verified, Caputo fractional derivative gives the same result as I have posted using simple definition. And as I have mentioned, Caputo definition is more consistent with regular (integer) derivative (it gives 0 for constants). Please see for details; http://homepages.vub.ac.be/~mishteva/papers/Ishteva_MScThesis.pdf